# A formula for representation

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra. Do you confirm the following discussion?

Let us consider a representation $\pi:A\to B(H)$. We denote $M_{\pi}$ by the von Neumann algebra generated by $\pi(A)$. If we denote $V_{\pi}$ by the predual of $M_{\pi}$, then it may be assumed as a closed subspace of $A^*$. Indeed $V_{\pi}$ 
is an invariant subspace of $A^*$. Therefore there is a unique central projection $e_{\pi}$ in $A^{**}$ (which is also called the support of $\pi$) with 
$$V_{\pi}=e^{\perp}_{\pi}A^* ~~~\textrm{which implies that}~~~M_{\pi}=e_{\pi}A^{**}$$
To sum up with, for the representation $\pi$, we find the following two formulas:

1- $\pi$  is just the restriction mapping $a\to a_{|_{V_{\pi}}}$

2- $\pi$ is given by $a\to ae_{\pi}$.